# Scala way of applying function to list and getting highest result with input

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
best_acc = 0
for split in split_candidates:
    acc = self.get_split_score(t_series_distances, split)
    if acc > best_acc:
        best_acc = acc
        best_split = split
return best_acc, best_split
```

What is the scala way of doing this ? I need to apply get_split_score function to a collection and get the highest value this function outputs as well as the input(element in original list) that caused this output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` to construct a sequence of `(score, split)` pairs and then use `maxBy` to find the pair with the highest score:

```
splitCandidates.map(c => (getSplitScore(tSeriesDistances, c), c)).maxBy(_._1)
```